# jQuery - run a function after drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery-ui draggable and droppable.
I want to run a function just after any draggable item dropped anywhere in the body.

I did this, but it wont work:

```
jQuery(document).drop(function(){
    alert('A draggable item dropped somewhere');
});
```

Comment: how is your `droppable` configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
 drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

view the example code here: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/
you want something like:

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({ alert('dropped'); });
```

It should workif you add the droppable id to the body tag.